# Remove Punctuation From Text Then Store As Dictionary In Data Column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I need help with some code. I need remove punctuation from text in a function then apply this function to a column in a dataframe column.  I need to count the frequency of each word in the resulting string which I called review_without_punctuation. I then need to store the count for each word in a  column as a dictionary.  I've tried a function that count words and apply it to review_without_punctuation but the function does not run.

Here is my attempt.

```
def remove_punctuation(text):

    import string
    from string import maketrans
    ##Multiply by number of punctuation characters
    table = string.maketrans('.?,!:;_', 7 * " ")
    ##takes care of float has no attribute translate
    products['review'] = products.fillna({'review':''})
    return text.translate(table)
review_without_punctuation = products['review'].apply(remove_punctuation)
##products['word_count'] = graphlab.text_analytics.count_words(review_without_punctuation)

products['word_count']= review_without_punctuation.str.split().str.len()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From running your code, it looks like you are okay on the punctuation removal. I am not familiar with `graphlab` but the `collections` library has good tools for counting.

I've altered your code to use the `collections.Counter` datatype to create a word count dictionary for each row in your Series. Note that I moved the imports to the beginning of the code (generally good practice). I also included a test `pandas.Dataframe` object which is good so that people have what they need to test your code and verify results.

```
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd
import string

def remove_punctuation(text):
    word_counter = Counter() # Initialize our counter
    ##Multiply by number of punctuation characters
    table = string.maketrans('.?,!:;_', 7 * " ")
    ##takes care of float has no attribute translate
    products['review'] = products.fillna({'review':''})
    for word in text.translate(table).split():
        word_counter[word] += 1
    return dict(word_counter)

products = pd.DataFrame({'review':['apple,orange','hello:goodbye']}) # test df
review_without_punctuation = products['review'].apply(remove_punctuation)
products['word_count']= review_without_punctuation
```

I modified the code in Python 3.x and I believe that `string.maketrans` is from 2.x so you may have to fix it if I didn't translate it back to 2.x correctly (I don't have that environment set up on my computer). My output is as follows:

```
In [1]: products
Out[1]: 
          review                  word_count
0   apple,orange   {'apple': 1, 'orange': 1}
1  hello:goodbye  {'hello': 1, 'goodbye': 1}
```

Does this give you the result you are looking for with your original dataset?

Comment: Thanks I will check it out and let you know.  Either way I've learned something new and I'm grateful.